# Removing levels in data frame when importing csv data

Tags: r, csv

I am importing csv data to R using

```
data <- read.csv(file="file_name.csv")
```

This data has 9 columns and 5000 rows and data values are real number. Now I want to use this data as a data frame. But the first columns occurs with some levels. I don't want this levels.

Here is a sample data in .csv format

[image]

Could any one please help me to remove the levels from the first column after it is imported to R.

Here is my attempt:

```
data$col_1 = as.numeric(as.character(data$col_1))
```

But it showing warning:

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: It is same warning as I wrote in my attempt.

Comment: You should include sample data to make this problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) otherwise it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: I added sample data.

Comment: Your screenshot does not paint the full picture. There are probably values *somewhere* which are not unambiguously numbers. Also, your columns in the screenshot are called `Var_1 Var_2 Var_3` but your code acts on `col_1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read.csv` is basically a wrapper around `read.table`, turn off `stringsAsFactors` will work.

```
data <- read.csv(file="filename", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then I guess that column will be treated as `characters`. Then you can do this to convert to numeric.:

```
data$col <- as.numeric(data$col)
```

Note: if you have a clean column containing only numbers, `read.csv` will read in as numeric intelligently, if it read in as `factors`, it means R detected something that is text or nonnumeric. you might want to pay attention to the `warnings` see which records got converted to NA due to what reason.

For example, I have a csv file.

[image]

When I read in, the id column will be treated as `characters` simply because there is one row contains `ohyeah` (if it is empty or NA, R still will treat as column as numeric). I would recommend you to first subset the records that have been contaminated, see if it is a big issue or not.

```
> subset(data, is.na(as.numeric(id)))
  name     id
4  dan ohyeah
Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercio
```

Comment: Thanks for attention. This code is giving a warning: NAs introduced by coercion.